# NVIDIA 480i Component Output Modelines

Tags: nvidia, xorg, modelines

I have an old Sony CRT (480i) and NVIDIA 6600LE video card with Component (YPbPr) output.

Everything is plugged in. BIOS screen works fine, but Linux distributions are outputting either 480p or the wrong hz (I'm expecting 60hz.) The content is visible, but scrolls across the screen rapidly.

I recall coming across modelines when using Redhat 6.2 back in the early 2000s.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFree86_Modeline

What would an Xorg.conf look like for this type of configuration on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

Solution turned out to be pretty simple. Make sure you read the `man` pages for `xrandr`, especially for `overscan` and `transform`, because your settings are likely going to be different.

Use `xrandr --prop` to see available settings and displays. Replace `TV-1` with your display device.

```
alias tvout='xrandr --output TV-1'
tvout --off
tvout --set mode NTSC-M
tvout --set overscan 0
tvout --set "flicker reduction" 0
tvout --transform 1.0,0,0,0,0.75,0,0,0,1
tvout --auto
tvout --Left-of DVI-I-1
```

There is no harm in playing around with the transform settings. You may have to disable/enable your display for changes to be applied.

For example:

```
tvout --off
tvout --transform 2.0,0,0,0,1.5,0,0,0,1
tvout --auto
```

**Custom Modelines**

You may also add custom modelines. Easiest working list is: https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Working_with_Modelines

I did not find adding custom modelines to be necessary, but it can be done completely through `xrandr`. There is no need to modify the `xorg` configuration.